# Change boolean data field from API react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

i want to change one field from false to true. I get the data from an api and the data is:

```
{
"all": 1,
"data": [
        {
          "name": "day1",
          "read": false
       },
       {
          "name": "day2",
          "read": false
       },
}
```

what i want is when i click one button the value changed.

I do that but only update the state and not the value read.

```
const [readData, setReadData] = React.useState(data.read);

const handleClick = () => {
     setReadData(!readData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need some correction.

`data` is an array.

`setState` call should be like this.

```
const [readData, setReadData] = React.useState(data[0].read);
```

Comment: hmm, and if i have more than 1 "day"?, because i want to change all read fields

Comment: Its upto your form logic. Just access that day which we want to manage through state